# Print Visually Pleasing DataFrames in For Loop in Jupyter Notebook Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

Say I have these two Data Frames in a list,

```
sm = pd.DataFrame([["Forever", 'BenHarper'],["Steel My Kisses", 'Kack Johnson'],\
                  ["Diamond On the Inside",'Xavier Rudd'],[ "Count On Me", "Bruno Mars"]],\
                   columns=["Song", "Artist"])

pm = pd.DataFrame([["I am yours", 'Jack Johnson'],["Chasing Cars", 'Snow Patrol'],\
                  ["Kingdom Comes",'Cold Play'],[ "Time of your life", "GreenDay"]],\
                   columns=["Song", "Artist"])

df_list = [sm,pm]
```

Now, when I want to print both data frames while iterating, I get something like this,

```
for i in df_list:
    print(i)
```

Result,

```
                  Song        Artist
0                Forever     BenHarper
1        Steel My Kisses  Kack Johnson
2  Diamond On the Inside   Xavier Rudd
3            Count On Me    Bruno Mars
                Song        Artist
0         I am yours  Jack Johnson
1       Chasing Cars   Snow Patrol
2      Kingdom Comes     Cold Play
3  Time of your life      GreenDay
```

However, when we do `df_list[0]` it prints in a pleasing tabular manner,

[image]

Can I get that same way in a visually pleasing way when I loop through the list and print Data Frame?? I have been searching and no luck yet. Any ideas how to do that?

(Sorry, if this is something that is normal in python, as I am new to Python and Jupyter, visually pleasing ones make me feel happy to see)

Answer (score 86, accepted):

You can use this:

```
from IPython.display import display

for i in df_list:
    display(i)
```

[image]

Learn more tricks about rich and flexible formatting at [Jupyter Notebook Viewer](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/ipython/ipython/blob/master/examples/IPython%20Kernel/Rich%20Output.ipynb)

Comment: In latest Python Jupyter version, `from IPython.display import display` is not needed!

Answer (score 0):

Simply use

```
for df in dfs:
    dispaly(df)
```

No import needed.