# jupyter-notebook: print fine table in a cycle

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

When I input a name of dataframe in jupyter-notebook, it prints a pretty table:

```
fail_data
```

[image]

It can even recognize the TeX notation.

But when I need to print the data in the cycle, the output looks not so good:

```
fail_data_gr = fail_data.groupby('test_name')
for k, v in fail_data_gr:
    print(v)
```

[image]

How to make this output looking like the first one?

Comment: Try `from IPython.display import display; for .... in ... : display(v)`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Print Visually Pleasing DataFrames in For Loop in Jupyter Notebook Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51288869/print-visually-pleasing-dataframes-in-for-loop-in-jupyter-notebook-pandas)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Displaying in jupyter notebooks delegate to the `IPython.display` module. When printing inside a loop, `print` dumps the `__str__` representation of the DataFrame, which does no special rendering.

So, in summary, change

```
for k, v in fail_data_gr:
    print(v)
```

to

```
from IPython.display import display
for k, v in fail_data_gr:
    display(v)
```